# Sending information to server and getting processed data back using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to make an application using nodejs, express and ejs. What I'm aiming to do is submitting a form to the server, trigger a server function which processes the data to get some result, and getting my page to display the result without reloading the whole page.

Currently this is what I have:

ejs

```
<form method = "GET" action = "/sendinput"
...something here
</form>
```

app.js

```
app.get('/sendinput', function (req, res) {
     result = processData(req.query);
});
```

I manage to get the function to run when the form is submitted, but after that the page keeps loading even after the function finishes running. I'm also not sure how to fetch the result and let the form segment of the html displays it without reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the page from loading, use [res.end();](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) 
it will signal the server that your function is done.

```
app.get('/sendinput', function (req, res) {
   result = processData(req.query);
   res.end();
});
```

Comment: But then I got redirected to a blank page, is there any way I can stay on the page where I submit the form?

Comment: change res.end()  to `res.send('submitted')`.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I solve it by using Ajax, which doesn't prompt the page for a reload and manage to get what I want.